# How to trigger ng-model value in angularjs if browser auto fill scripts filled out the forms

Tags: forms, validation, angularjs, model

So I have a generic problem with chrom autofill scripts and my guess is that for all autofill script this would be a problem.

When input fields get set with autofills, how do I register them with the ng-model value.
e.g. (html, ui, angular javascript)

```
username: <input ng-model="username"/>,   username: [      ],   $scope.username = ""
```

if i type Blanka, I get

```
username: <input ng-model="username" value="Blanka"/>,   username: [Blanka],   $scope.username = "Blanka"
```

but with chrom autofill it seems to be doing

```
username: <input ng-model="username"/>,   username: [Blanka],   $scope.username = ""
```

how do i inject values into ng-model whenever there's autofilled data.

Comment: Same problem with tools like 1Password.

Comment: Similar to: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14965968/angularjs-browser-autofill-workaround-by-using-a-directive

Comment: @user2167582 please remove your question.