# AngularJS - using a form and auto-completion

Tags: angularjs, autocomplete, autofill

I have the following code in a partial page used for login...

```
<div class="container">
    <form autocomplete="on" data-ng-submit="checkCredentials()" class="form-signin">
        <h2 class="form-signin-heading">Login page</h2>
        <label for="email"> <b>User e-mail</b> </label>
        <input required autocomplete="on" name="email" type="text" data-ng-model="modelLogin.email" class="input-block-level" placeholder="Email address">
        <label for="pass"> <b>Password</b> </label>
        <input required autocomplete="on" name="pass" type="password" data-ng-model="modelLogin.password" class="input-block-level" placeholder="Password">
        <button style="margin-bottom:1em" class="btn btn-large btn-primary" type="submit">Log in</button>
    </form>
</div>
```

...which is ng-included from my one and only main page (index.html):

```
<body data-ng-controller="controllerLogin">
    <div data-ng-include="getMainpageBasedOnLoginStatus()">
    </div>
</body>
```

...with the **getMainpageBasedOnLoginStatus()** function returning the appropriate path to either the *partials/loginPage.html* shown above or the *partials/mainApplicationPage.html* (my main app entrypoint). The **checkCredentials()** call done via ng-submit performs a webservice call to get back login success/failure, and does the proper update in a global model variable - so that subsequent calls to **getMainpageBasedOnLoginStatus()** return the 'ok-you-are-logged-in' page (*partials/mainApplicationPage.html*).

This login scheme cannot be hacked, because even if the client code is somehow changed to direct to the *main app* partial instead of the *login* partial, the server side will simply not function properly (web service requests simply won't function and return 406 errors).

All is well - it works. Except for... autofill.

The login/password fields are neither autocompleted, nor autofilled with Chrome 29. Same in Firefox 23: the login/password fields are not autofilled, but the login one (only the login one, not the password one!) is autocompleted - but not auto-filled.

Note that I have used the HTML5 attribute 'autocomplete' in both the form and the two inputs - with no result whatsoever.

Googling has revealed others who face related issues ( [Remember Password with AngularJS and ng-submit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18586938/remember-password-with-angularjs-and-ng-submit) ) , with no answer...  I could not upvote that question (I am too green yet, SO-wise).

There is also an open ticket on AngularJS ( https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/1460 ) that is there for 7 months, and tells the rather sad tale of people where autofill *was actually "working", browser-wise,* for some people, except that the underlying model was not updated... and a comment there from someone called "bigbag" that the feature is now disabled, for that reason.

I find this rather unacceptable from the point of view of AngularJS - surely I am not the first one that needs autofill/autocomplete in his app's forms, am I? Or do I have to abandon the Single Page theory and revert back to the nasty form *action* and separate server-side provided login.html/main.html responses to get autofill/autocomplete working?

Any help/advice most appreciated and desperately needed...

Comment: Unbelievable: 2h after posting this, Firefox 24 came out, where autofill works! Guess I now have to wait for Chrome to fix this, too...

Comment: Maybe you can check up this article on the problem: http://timothy.userapp.io/post/63412334209/form-autocomplete-and-remember-password-with-angularjs

Answer (score 5):

Here is an alternative solution that is semantically sound AngularJS: http://victorblog.com/2014/01/12/fixing-autocomplete-autofill-on-angularjs-form-submit/

```
myApp.directive('formAutofillFix', function() {
  return function(scope, elem, attrs) {
    // Fixes Chrome bug: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/angular/6NlucSskQjY
    elem.prop('method', 'POST');

    // Fix autofill issues where Angular doesn't know about autofilled inputs
    if(attrs.ngSubmit) {
      setTimeout(function() {
        elem.unbind('submit').submit(function(e) {
          e.preventDefault();
          elem.find('input, textarea, select').trigger('input').trigger('change').trigger('keydown');
          scope.$apply(attrs.ngSubmit);
        });
      }, 0);
    }
  };
});
```

Then you attach the directive to your form:

```
<form ng-submit="submitLoginForm()" form-autofill-fix>
  <div>
    <input type="email" ng-model="email" ng-required />
    <input type="password" ng-model="password" ng-required />
    <button type="submit">Log In</button>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: I just fully implemented this directive and it is not working. Is this still relevant?

Comment: May not be, a lot has changed in Angular core, even over "minor" version bumps, esp. with regard to which eventbindings they use, etc. I wish I would have documented the version of Angular this was written for because that will almost certainly be a factor for this fix.

Answer (score 2):

A nice thing about autocomplete is that it leaves the form $pristine.

You can do a simple check and get the value when needed:

```
if($scope.[form_name].$pristine){
   var input document.getElementById([input_id]);
   var input_value = input.value
}
```

You can then submit the value or replace it e.g `$scope.[module] = input.value`