# AngularJS: Login form does not reset on reload

Tags: html, angularjs, forms

I am using angular to create a login form. The html is as follows:

```
<div class="container" ng-controller="loginCtrl">
    <div class="card card-container" >
        <img id="profile-img" class="profile-img-card" src="//ssl.gstatic.com/accounts/ui/avatar_2x.png" />
        <p id="profile-name" class="profile-name-card"></p>
        <form class="form-signin" ng-submit="authenticate()">
            <input type="text" id="username" class="form-control" ng-model="username" placeholder="username" required autofocus>
            <input type="password" id="password" class="form-control" ng-model="password" placeholder="password" required>
            <button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block btn-signin" type="submit">Sign in</button>
        </form>
     </div>
</div>
```

My controller in angular:

```
ristoreApp.controller("loginCtrl", 
    ['$scope', '$location', 'loginFactory', 
    function($scope, $location, loginFactory){
        $scope.username = '';
        $scope.password = '';
        $scope.authenticate = function() {
            loginFactory.login($scope.username, $scope.password)
            .then(function(response) {
                loginFactory.setCredentials($scope.username, $scope.password);
                $location.path('/home');
            }, function errorCallBack(response) {
                console.log("Failed auth");
                $location.path('/login');
            });
        }
    }]);
```

The page remembers the username/password and shows them in the form even if I clear cache and hard reload. How do I clear the form every time I refresh the page?

Comment: Could you show us your loginCtrl code?

Comment: @FelippeDuarte controller added.

Comment: I had a similar bug in chrome. Have you tried adding the attribute autocomplete="off"

Comment: Your code seems ok. I think this is a browser behavior. You could block any kind of autocomplete, but you really want to do that?

Comment: there is a something like that: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21168367/angularjs-chrome-autocomplete-dilemma

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try setting 'new-password' for the 'autocomplete' attribute in your password field:

```
<input type="password" id="password" autocomplete="new-password" class="form-control" ng-model="password" placeholder="password" required>
```