# Angular form chrome prevents autofil username and password

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-chrome, autofill

I have below markup for input textbox

```
 <ng-form id="LogForm" name="LogForm">
<input type="email" ng-enter="!LogForm.$invalid ? login() : ''" id="emailAddress" name="emailAddress" ng-model="loginForm.emailAddress" ng-pattern="/^[A-Za-z0-9._%+-]+@("@")[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}$/" required />
 </ng-form>
```

I can see chrome saves password for the site, but it does not auto fill them

Any suggestion

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angularjs Chrome autocomplete dilemma](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21168367/angularjs-chrome-autocomplete-dilemma)

Comment: that is autocomplete, but my question related to autofil from saved password