# form has no method 'submit' (angularjs form autofill issue workaround)

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm running into an issue where my model will not update when the browser autofills the field. I've selected an answer by [Ezekiel Victor](https://stackoverflow.com/users/444692/ezekiel-victor) which looks like what I need, but I'm having trouble implementing it.

```
angular.module('roomsApp.directives', []).directive('formAutofillFix', ['$timeout',
function ($timeout) {
  return function(scope, elem, attrs) {
    // Fixes Chrome bug: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/angular/6NlucSskQjY
    elem.prop('method', 'POST');

    // Fix autofill issues where Angular doesn't know about autofilled inputs
    if(attrs.ngSubmit) {
      setTimeout(function() {
        elem.unbind('submit').submit(function(e) {
          e.preventDefault();
          elem.find('input, textarea, select').trigger('input').trigger('change').trigger('keydown');
          scope.$apply(attrs.ngSubmit);
        });
      }, 0);
    }
  };
});
```

I get an error on the line:

```
elem.unbind('submit').submit(function(e) {
```

**In Firefox: elem.unbind(...).submit is not a function**

**In Chrome: Object [object Object] has no method 'submit'**

After digging around online, the most common thing that causes this error is when an input field is named "submit", but mine is not suffering from that particular issue

```
<form form-autofill-fix  ng-submit="login()" id="login-fields">
    <input form="login-fields" ng-model="userLogin" type="email" name="username" ng-required/>
    <input form="login-fields" ng-model="userPassword" type="password" name="password" ng-required />
    <button form="login-fields" name="login"">Login </button>
</form>
```

I'd appreciate any insight into this.

**References:**

http://victorblog.com/2014/01/12/fixing-autocomplete-autofill-on-angularjs-form-submit/

["Submit is not a function" error in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/833032/submit-is-not-a-function-in-javascript)

[AngularJS - using a form and auto-completion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18848519/angularjs-using-a-form-and-auto-completion)

[AngularJS browser autofill workaround by using a directive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14965968/angularjs-browser-autofill-workaround-by-using-a-directive/16800988#16800988)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try converting/casting your elem variable to an angular element like this ...

```
elem = angular.element(elem);
```

And then try to `unbind`

Comment: Hi, same issue, I tryed the fix suggested from @dcodesmith, but this is not working for me. Any other suggestion?

Comment: Ok, got it. 
I replaced this :
```elem.unbind(‘submit’).submit(function(e) {```
with this :
```elem.unbind(‘submit’).bind(‘submit’, function(e) {```
and it is working now...

Comment: Another update, if you don't have jQuery loaded in your project ```.trigger```will not work. Use instead ```.triggerHandler```

Answer (score 0):

Just ran into the same issue, but luckily chrome fires a change-event when autofilling.

My fix was the following:

```
<input ng-model="invoiceAddress.firstName" ng-model-options="validatorBehavior" .... >
```

Where validatorBehaviour in the contoller is:

```
$scope.validatorBehavior = { updateOn: 'change blur' };
```

That way your model will be updated on change, and therefore on autofill.