# ios safari input text disappearing

Tags: ios, angularjs, safari

I am having a strange problem with input in ios safari
[as shown here.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZHQSm.png)

The input is part of an angular app and has some basic checks for ng-length and ng-pattern. Initially as you type all the characters are showed, but if you play around with the page a bit, like tapping out, scrolling up and down, then tapping in again only the first 2 letters of what you type will show and the rest will be invisible, but the cursor will still move.

The input also uses a custom web font, but removing it did not fix the problem.

Is this a known bug and is there a workaround?

Comment: I've seen issues with Safari autofill. Do you know if your browser is autofilling for you? Here's a thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14965968/angularjs-browser-autofill-workaround-by-using-a-directive

Comment: I have all this on the input: autocomplete="off" autocorrect="off" autocapitalize="off" spellcheck="false"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found my problem: an iframe being positioned absolute, hidden, from which I listen to the resize event as a solution of monitoring a div width. Removing position:absolute from it fixed it.

Comment: Hey. I had the same problem. Do you know why this is causing issues with iOS devices? I had commented my css code out.

Comment: I don't know why it happens. There lots of bugs in iOS Safari that don't make any sense.

Answer (score 5):

You can add

```
transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
```

to the input's style.

This will form a new [stacking context](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Positioning/Understanding_z_index/The_stacking_context) and solve the problem.

Comment: This is my second time fixing this issue. `transform: translateZ(0px)` worked previously, but apparently not anymore. translate3d did the trick in Safari 12.1 on iOS 12.4