# Weird iOS device specific issue with form input

Tags: html, ios, css

This did not work on the actual iPhone X hardware

http://braindrain.developmentserver.me/webapp/page/login

If you tap the username field and type, the cursor moves with no text being displayed.

I’m not sure how to fix it. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the input is getting updated when you start typing.

I would investigate the angular part of this form.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36697835/ios-safari-input-text-disappearing Is my issue and I applied the CSS fix but it did not resolve the problem